# c++ CreateProcess() won't work with app and args with forward slash "/" - worked with App=NULL

Tags: c++, winapi, createprocess

**Solution:"**

```
    ShellAndWait(NULL, _FinalShellStrCmd, "WAIT", 240, 1);
```

Using stringstream to combine App and Arg into _FinalShellStrCmd, leave first arg as NULL. It worked fine with either forward or back slashes. Thanks all again.

I am using boost to get current path, then I get "d:/bin/test. 
Now, I try to call ShellAndWait() below with CreateProcess() library function. With backslash "\ in the directory path eg.. d:\bin\test. it works like charm.

I had printout the app path and args to dos prompt, then I copy them and past to the dos prompt, it executed OK. Example, D:/bin/test/test.exe d:/bin/test/test.dat
                                       app-path               args

if I put the app-path and args to ShellWandWait function below, and it did nothing. I am suspected that the CreateProcess() would not take path or directory with forward slash "/". 
Anyone give me some lights here? Thanks again.

```
int BasicExcelCell::ShellAndWait(char *AppName, char *AppArgument, char *Wait, DWORD       TimeOut=0, DWORD IgnoreErrorFlag=0)
{

PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInfo; //This is what we get as an [out] parameter
STARTUPINFO StartupInfo; //This is an [in] parameter
ZeroMemory(&StartupInfo, sizeof(StartupInfo));
StartupInfo.cb = sizeof StartupInfo ; //Only compulsory field


TimeOut =  TimeOut * 1000;

if (Wait == "NOWAIT")
    ShellExecute(NULL,"open",AppName, AppArgument," ", SW_SHOW );
else //WAIT
{
    //printf("ShellExecute WAIT\n");
    printf("Appname:%s  AppArgs:%s\n", AppName, AppArgument);
    UINT olderrormode;

    if (IgnoreErrorFlag)
    {
          olderrormode = SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS|SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX);
    }

    if (CreateProcess(AppName, AppArgument,
                      NULL,NULL,FALSE,CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,NULL,
                      NULL,&StartupInfo,&ProcessInfo))
    {
        std::cout<<"WaitingSingleOjbec"<<endl;
        DWORD dwret = WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess,TimeOut);
        switch (dwret)
        {
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            break;
        case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
        default:
            TerminateProcess(ProcessInfo.hProcess,0);
            break;
        }
        CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
        CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);
    }

    if (IgnoreErrorFlag)
    {
        SetErrorMode(olderrormode);
    }
}

return 0;

}
```

Comment: maybe you need to escape the slashes? "//"

Comment: Show your code calling the function - not enough info as is. (For instance, do you call it with "NOWAIT"? We can't tell, so we don't know which branch it takes.) Also, you should change your function to define dwRet earlier (along with the other vars) and initialize it to 0. Then change the final return to return dwRet; that way you get a possibly meaningful return value (whatever `WaitForSingleObject` returns, at least). As is, it always returns 0. While you're at it, change the wait parameter from a `char *` to an int or BOOL so you can pass TRUE or FALSE instead of a case-sensitive string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the answer: CreateProcess doesn't work with forward-slashes. Fix the slashes => the code works. Certain user-facing APIs and interfaces are more accepting than others

Comment: Thanks for all comments. Good to know. Is there alternate way to create process using boost? If not, I like to replace the "/" with "\\". I am using to boost replace regex, it does not work properly. any advise. Thanks.

Comment: `boost::algorithm::replace_all(path, "/", "\\");`

Comment: CreateProcess does work with forward-slashes on Windows 7. I'm guessing this is a version-specific feature (or bug).

Comment: Feature - WinNT uses backslashes in paths. Accepting slashes is an undocumented extension.

Comment: `boost::algorithm::replace_all(TraceConfig.str(), "/", "\\");
boost::algorithm::replace_all(ParserExe.str(), "/", "\\");`
it does not work for me for some reason. TraceConfig and ParserExe are stringstream type.

Comment: `std::string test(TraceConfig.str());
replace(test.begin(),test.end(),'/','\\');`   it worked this way. using boost replace, I got no lucks. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good reason CreateProcess won't work with forward slashes: Windows programs often use them as a command line option specifier (like "dir /w" or "format c: /q"). An old baggage from DOS dictates that that forward-slash-arguments don't need to be separated by a space - so the following format for DOS/Windows console command is also valid: "dir/w", "format c:/q".

I guess the windows API programmers wanted CreateProcess to support this, so they decided not to parse forward slashes as path separators. Compatibility with DOS and existing Windows programs was more important than compatibility with POSIX.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to create a `boost:filesystem::path` object and then use `make_preferred()`. Let boost library handle the character replace job.

Comment: make_preferred() has been removed from boost? I had seen a lot of bug report for this feature. I could not find it from latest boost version. It sounds like a good solution convert / to \\.

Comment: I guess you are right, https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5434 link says that it had been an issue but its fixed now. But it does not specify the target milestone. It internally uses `std::replace(m_pathname.begin(), m_pathname.end(), L'/', L'\\');`. So I guess that should work.